# Angular 2 NgIf, dont render container element on condition but show its child elements

Tags: angular

How do you do something like the following in **angular 2**? I've written it in pseudo code to help explain better.

I have tried **applying classes** but I **don't want it to render the container div** if possible.

I have also tried the **< template >** tag but I may be missing something. Thanks

```
<!-- ngIf: isPromo -->
<div class="promoContainer">
<!-- ngIf end -->

<div class="item">...</item>

<!-- ngIf: isPromo -->
</div>
<!-- ngIf end -->
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to create a component for your inner HTML and use ngIf to switch between the encapsulated version and the version without encapsulation like this:

```
<div class="promoContainer" *ngIf='isPromo'>
    <promotable-component></promotable-component>
</div>

<promotable-component *ngIf='!isPromo'></promotable-component>
```

Where you have a Component defined like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'promotable-component',
  template: '<div class="item">...</item>'
})
export class PromotableComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to try this simply

```
<!--if-->
<div class="promoContainer" *ngIf='isPromo'>    
    <div class="item">...</item>
</div>

<!--else-->
<div class="item" *ngIf='!isPromo'>...</item>
```

Comment: This causes duplicate content