# Angular 2+, Display a container element only if a condition applies but display the children

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a grid like view for a list of Angular components and I need to display a maximum of 4 components in the same row.

The closest question that I found is this one: [Angular 2 NgIf, dont render container element on condition but show its child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961258/angular-2-ngif-dont-render-container-element-on-condition-but-show-its-child-el)

But it works if the container has only one child. Also this is what I tried first(I know that I can use an else case):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pair of responsePair;let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i % 4 == 0">
    <div class="row">
      <app-report-tile></app-report-tile>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="i % 4 != 0">
    <app-report-tile></app-report-tile>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The row container is printed only for the 4th elment and I need the next 3 child components to be part of this row container.

Is there a way to not render an HTML element in some conditions?

Comment: can you create stackblitz example for that??

Comment: This is not a particular case, I just need to hide the container in some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UnluckyAj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9379329/unluckyaj) gave me an idea and I found the answer by myself, I create only 1 row and get the next elements in advance:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pair of responsePair;let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i % 4 == 0">
    <div class="row">
      <app-report-tile *ngIf="responsePair[i] !== undefined" [data]="responsePair[i]" ></app-report-tile>
      <app-report-tile *ngIf="responsePair[i + 1] !== undefined" [data]="responsePair[i + 1]"></app-report-tile>
      <app-report-tile *ngIf="responsePair[i + 2] !== undefined" [data]="responsePair[i + 2]"></app-report-tile>
      <app-report-tile *ngIf="responsePair[i + 3] !== undefined" [data]="responsePair[i + 3]"></app-report-tile>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Make sure that you use *ngIf on each component in order to avoid exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your requirement:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtjzic)

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pair of responsePair;let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i%4 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This looks good, I will try it now. But this will not generate duplicated components? When the "i" variable will be incremented?

Comment: dont use 'i' it will generate duplicate as well i have taken for my use only.

Comment: In my case I need to use the index. I will take my components from and Array using the "i" variable. It was good your example, that for each row I use i+1, i+2, i+3, but then I need to add somehow a +3 to the index.

Comment: yes you can do that thing that's why i have taken the scenario of indexes

Comment: I need to search if this is possible.